# AirPods connect to correct device

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, airpods

I own AirPods and connect to by my iMac (for video conference) and iPhone (for phone calls).

How do I get the AirPods to switch to the device that I want to use?

I can't turn bluetooth off on the iMac because then the mouse stops working. If I select AirPods on the iPhone when I am on a call nothing happens. But if I restart the computer then I can use it on the iPhone while the computer is not on bluetooth.

Comment: You could always disconnect your airpods from iMac without disabling bluetooth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Under the *Listen with your AirPods* section of this Apple support document:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207010)

> Follow these steps to use your AirPods to play audio from a different
> device or to switch the audio to different headphones or speakers.
>
> **On your iOS device**
>
> Open Control Center. Press deeply or touch and hold
> the audio card in the upper-right corner of Control Center to control
> audio. Tap the airplay icon, then choose the device you want from the list.*
>
> **On your Mac**
>
> Click the sound icon in the menu bar and choose your AirPods* or other speakers
> under Output Device.
>
> *AirPods appear only when they're nearby and ready to use.